# count items for each category sql php

Tags: php, sql, count

using sql and php.

I have the following table schema

```
id | item_id | category_id
```

I've sample data in this table

```
id  | item_id | category_id

1   | 1525       | shoes
2   | 2565       | shoes
3   | 2558       | shirts
4   | 2885       | shirts
5   | 3545       | shirts
6   | 1885       | belts
```

Requirement: I need to count how many items are in each category, and echo the count and item_ids

for example "category shoes has 2 items - 1525,2565" 
I need to do this for all categories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT category_id, COUNT(*) as num_items, GROUP_CONCAT(item_id) AS items
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY category_id
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the query code, how do I echo out the categoryid and item numbers from the results?

for example "category shoes has 2 items - 1525,2565"

Comment: `echo "category $row[category_id] has $row[num_items] items - $row[items]"`.

Comment: Every PHP+MySQL tutorial should show how to echo the results of a query.